# Linux Command to find Strings in Binary or non ascii file

Tags: linux, grep, binary, strings

Is there any linux command to extracts all the ascii strings from an executable or other binary file? I suppose I could do it with a grep, but I remember hearing somewhere that such a command existed?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The command you are looking for is **`strings`**

Its name is quite self-explanatory, it retrieves any printable string from a given file.

*`man strings`* gives:

> ***STRINGS(1)***
>
> *NAME*
>      **strings** - find the printable strings in a object, or other binary, file
>
> *SYNOPSIS*
>   **`strings [ - ] [ -a ] [ -o ] [ -t format ] [ -number ] [ -n number ] [--] [file ...]`**

Comment: In some use cases, white space, including newlines, is considered "ascii". GNU `strings` option `-w` (`--include-all-whitespace`) might help in those cases.

Comment: awesome! I didn't know such command existed. Now I can finally grep files containing a mixture of text and non-printable data.

Answer (score 17):

The *strings* command is the way to go for this particular type of problems. Sometimes you also have to pipe it out to *grep*.

For example:

```
strings somebinaryfile | grep textuwanttofind
```

Answer (score 5):

The command does exist, and is called.... strings!

Answer (score 4):

A problem with using strings is that you don't see surrounding non printables and you have to be careful with the minimum string length.

A problem using

```
od -c FILE
```

or

```
hexdump -C FILE
```

is that a sequence can be difficult to find if it wraps a line.

Something I like a lot for this is [ZTreeWin](http://www.ztree.com/html/ztreewin.htm) running in WINE on Linux - you can do a lot with it but the searching in any file or editing binaries can be particularly useful.

The awesome ytree package is available for many Linux and Unix variants and has a good Hex dump view of any file but doesn't have the search that ZTreeWin (and its 16bit predecessor, XTree) have.

Answer (score 3):

The od command can do this:

```
od -c *filename*
```

Comment: yeah, that does extract the ASCII characters, but it's not really the strings, per se. I think that 'strings' is more useful for the majority of cases.

Answer (score 0):

If `strings` is not available (like with git-bash on Windows) - try something like this:

- `tr -d -c '[:print:]\n'`

Explanation: Delete (-d) all characters other than printable and newline.

Complement (-c): gives the opposite/inverse of the translate character list. In this case all non-printable non-newline characters.

Reference for the `tr` (translate) command: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tr-invocation.html

Similar answer from Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55360597/226625